# Litecoin Reaper GPU config

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration

I have just started GPU mining on my Nvida 560 (Not good cards for mining).
Heres the stats I'm getting, not sure If I have configured the settings correctly as my GPU temp is only 27C, is this right? I know Nvidia cards aren't that good for mining but should the temp be this low?

[image]

reaper.conf

```
kernel reaper.cl
save_binaries yes
enable_graceful_shutdown no
long_polling yes


mine litecoin
```

Litecoin.conf

```
host notroll.in
port 6332
user *****
pass *****


protocol litecoin

worksize 256
aggression max
threads_per_gpu 1
sharethreads 18
lookup_gap 2
gpu_thread_concurrency 6144
```

Comment: What .bat are you using to start the program?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't even consider mining on nVidia GPUs. Secondly, if you're using nVidia GPU, why do you use AMD APP? You should be using nVidia CUDA instead. Next thing, Reaper is NOT mining on your GPU on the screen given, but on CPU instead - that's clearly stated in the screenshot you provided (using all devices - and only CPU is listed).

@Tom: you don't have to supply any command line options to mine with Reaper, all config can be easily done via .conf files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [the other answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/20449/6218). But to be nicer. We all start somewhere. I mine on NVIDIA with CUDA miner and I use weMineLTC as my pool but P2Pool is the better route these days to protect from a 51% attack. BUT weMineLTC is easy to config and useful to get your berings.